# Is there a case insensitive find-file-in-tags?

Tags: emacs, find

`find-file-in-tags` is great in fetching files in a large code base. However, it is case sensitive. Is there a case insensitive version? If not, is there there an easy way to make it case insensitive? I tried a bunch of things but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that `find-file-in-tags` is using `string-match` to do the matching, setting the value of `case-fold-search` should do the trick.

It does for me.

Note: since `find-file-in-tags` isn't distributed with Emacs, you might want to include a [link to the package](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/find-file-in-tags) you're using in your question.  It'd help people answer your question.

Comment: Hmmm, didn't work for me. case-fold-search was already set and so was tags-case-fold-search, although I don't think the latter matters. Here is my example: The files in "TAGS" are Foo.cpp and Bar.cpp, and I am searching for "foo". No match.

Comment: @Fadi I'm not sure what the problem is then.  Have you tried running emacs with `-q` and only loading `find-file-in-tags`?  Perhaps there's something else in your .emacs that's interfering...